# Books to learn about the historical background of the SET THEORY?

Tags: set-theory, book-recommendation

Can you suggest a book that would help me in understanding how the set theory evolve in history? (Need Cantor to all the way up to Godel and more modern facts such as continuum hypothesis)

Comment: José Ferreiros, [Labyrinth of Thought: A History of Set Theory and Its Role in Modern Mathematics (Springer, 1999)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Labyrinth_of_Thought/vrQLbbxGNMsC)

Comment: As a good starting point, by the same Author see SEP's entry [The Early Development of Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-early/).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you! for the recommendation

Comment: Gregory Moore has some great write ups; Aki Kanamori also has a lot of historical papers (focusing on specific people or problems).